# Using glob patterns not for default Grunt keys

Tags: gruntjs, glob, gruntfile, grunt-plugins

### 1. Summary

I can't set [**grunt-clean-console**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-clean-console) plugin, that it works for all my `.html` files.

---

### 2. Details

grunt-clean-console check browser console errors for `.html` files.

I want to check browser console errors for all `.html` files of my site. [**In official descripition**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-clean-console#install) I read, how plugin works for specific values of `url` key. I have many pages in my site; I don't want add each `.html` file separately. But I can't find, how I can use patterns.

I find, that I can use patterns for built-in Grunt `cwd`, `src`, `dest` keys. But how I can use glob (or another) patterns for custom keys as `url` of this plugin?

---

### 3. Data

- `Gruntfile.coffee`:

  ```coffee
  module.exports = (grunt) ->

      grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-clean-console'

      grunt.initConfig
          'clean-console':
              all:
                  options:
                      url: 'output/index.html'
      return
  ```
- **example** project configuration:

  ```text
  output
  │   404.html
  │   index.html
  │
  ├───KiraFirstFolder
  │       KiraFirstfile.html
  │
  └───KiraSecondFolder
          KiraSecondFile.html
  ```
- If I set specific values for `url` key without patterns as in example above, grunt-clean-console successfully works:

  ```text
  phantomjs: opening page output/index.html

  phantomjs: Checking errors after sleeping for 5000ms
  ok output/index.html

  phantomjs process exited with code 0

  Done.
  ```

#### 3.1. Steps to reproduce

I run in console:

```
grunt clean-console --verbose
```

---

### 4. Not helped

#### 4.1. Globbing

- [**Official documentation**](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns)
- `Gruntfile.coffee`:

  ```coffee
  module.exports = (grunt) ->

      grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-clean-console'

      grunt.initConfig
          'clean-console':
              all:
                  options:
                      url: 'output/**/*.html'
      return
  ```
- output:

  ```text
  phantomjs: opening page http://output/**/*.html

  phantomjs: Unable to load resource (#1URL:http://output/**/*.html)


  phantomjs:   phantomjs://code/runner.js:30 in onResourceError
  Error code: 3. Description: Host output not found

    phantomjs://code/runner.js:31 in onResourceError

  phantomjs: loading page http://output/**/*.html status fail

    phantomjs://code/runner.js:50

  phantomjs process exited with code 1
  url output/**/*.html has 1 error(s)
  >> one of the urls failed clean-console check
  Warning: Task "clean-console:all" failed. Use --force to continue.

  Aborted due to warnings.
  ```

#### 4.2. Building the object dinamically

- [**Official documentation**](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)
- `Gruntfile.coffee` (example):

  ```coffee
  module.exports = (grunt) ->

      grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-clean-console'

      grunt.initConfig
          'clean-console':
              all:
                  options:
                      url:
                          files: [
                              expand: true
                              cwd: "output/"
                              src: ['**/*.html']
                              dest: "output/"
                          ]
      return
  ```
- output:

  ```text
  File: [no files]
  Options: urls=[], timeout=5, url=["output/**/*.html"]

  Fatal error: missing url
  ```

#### 4.3. Templates

- [**Official documentation**](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates)
- `Gruntfile.coffee`:

  ```coffee
  module.exports = (grunt) ->

      grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-clean-console'

      grunt.initConfig
          'clean-console':
              all:
                  options:
                      url: '<%= kiratemplate %>'
          kiratemplate: ['output/**/*.html'],
      return
  ```
- output:

  ```text
  phantomjs: opening page http://output/**/*.html

  phantomjs: Unable to load resource (#1URL:http://output/**/*.html)


  phantomjs:   phantomjs://code/runner.js:30 in onResourceError
  Error code: 3. Description: Host output not found

    phantomjs://code/runner.js:31 in onResourceError
  loading page http://output/**/*.html status fail

    phantomjs://code/runner.js:50

  phantomjs process exited with code 1
  url output/**/*.html has 1 error(s)
  >> one of the urls failed clean-console check
  Warning: Task "clean-console:all" failed. Use --force to continue.

  Aborted due to warnings.
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function before the `grunt.initConfig` part that utilizes [`grunt.file.expand`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand). For instance:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-clean-console'

  // Add this function...
  function getFiles() { return grunt.file.expand('output/**/*.html'); }

  grunt.initConfig({
    'clean-console': {
      all: {
        options: {
          url: getFiles() // <-- invoke the function here.
        }
      }
    }
    // ...
  });

  // ...
}
```

**Notes:**

- The `getFiles` function returns an array of file paths for all `.html` files matching the given glob pattern, i.e. `'output/**/*.html'`.
- The value of the `options.url` property is set to `getFiles()` to invoke the function.